# UINavigationController white line glitch when swiping back

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a glitch happening when using the built-in swipe back gesture, going from a UIViewController with a UITableView to a UIViewController to a UICollectionView. There is a thin white line glitching at some point as if it was the left border of the current view controller.

In the image below, I've captured a screenshot, untouched on the left. On the right, it's the very **same** screenshot but I've highlighted the thin white line in pink. It looks way more disturbing on my iPhone 6 than here on screen.

[glitch http://sidlee.d.pr/16ck4/37icoodl+](http://sidlee.d.pr/16ck4/37icoodl+)

Comment: Is it only visible on iPhone6 or you can also see it on iPhone5 as well?

Comment: I haven't tested. But I got a solution just now: setting the UIView from the current view controller background to clear background solves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been spending hours on this, and just when I post the question on SO, I get to the solution. I'm not sure why the glitch happens, but it occurs that the thin white line is actually a piece of the UIView from the current view controller.

Anyway, **setting the UIView background color to clear color solves it.**